# Read XML file into hashmap and create new object

Tags: java, xml, hashmap, getelementsbytagname, xmlnodelist

I am trying to read XML into a `HashMap`, I am trying to read each XML node and create new object based on its contents.

How do I retrieve the value of each node of the XML?

For example : I need to retrieve `birthdate` value within my for loop and use it to create a new `studentInfo` object.

xml :

```
<students xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="students.xsd"><description>A bunch students and courses</description><student studentID="0144085" gender ="M"><firstname>Jack</firstname>
  <lastname>Blogs</lastname> <birthday day="21" month="04" year="1983"/><paper>Data Structures and Algorithms</paper><paper>Distributed and Mobile Systems</paper>     <paper>Software Engineering</paper><paper>Highly Secure Systems</paper><paper>Engineering Computations</paper><paper>Object Oriented Programming</paper></student>
```

code :

```
                //jf : set StudentINfoSet class properties
            this.description =  rootXMLNode.getElementsByTagName( "description" ).item( 0 ).getTextContent();
            studentMap =  new HashMap<String, StudentInfo>();
            NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName( "student" );
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
                StudentInfo si = new StudentInfo(Integer.toString(i)){};
                /*
                 * String studentID, String firstName, String lastName,
        String birthdate, String gender, char studentGender
                 * */
                this.studentMap.put(Integer.toString(i), si);
            }
            System.out.println("Number of students : "+nodeList.getLength());
```

Comment: Thanks guys, but I need to do it without using any library.

Comment: I think that I have found the solution for this.http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Answer (score 1):

I would use JAXB, see example here http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 1):

you should consider jaxb or simple framework to achieve this rather writing for loops and iterating over XML nodes

Answer (score 0):

You should use a unique identifier of your object as a hashmap key. I believer in your case studentID will be good candidate for key of your hashmap. Define your hashmap accordingly and save the elements as per the recommendation. You should be able to retrieve each student easily from the hashmap using studentID.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have solved this question. Here is my code. Thanks for the help.

```
public StudentInfoSet(InputStream in) {
    if (in != null) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            builderFactory.setValidating(false);
            builderFactory.setAttribute(JAXP_SCHEMA_LANGUAGE,W3C_XML_SCHEMA);
            DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            // parse the input stream
            document = builder.parse(in);
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            // JAXP
            Element rootXMLNode = document.getDocumentElement();

            //jf : set StudentINfoSet class properties
            this.description =  rootXMLNode.getElementsByTagName( "description" ).item( 0 ).getTextContent();
            studentMap =  new HashMap<String, StudentInfo>();
            NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName( "student" );
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
                StudentInfo si = new StudentInfo(Integer.toString(i)){};
                /*
                 * String studentID, String firstName, String lastName,
        String birthdate, String gender, char studentGender
                 * */
                //this.studentMap.put(Integer.toString(i), si);

                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + currentNode.getNodeName());

                if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) currentNode;

                    System.out.println("Staff id : " + eElement.getAttribute("firstname"));
                    System.out.println("First Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("Last Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("birthday").item(0).getTextContent());


                    NodeList studentPaperNodeList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("paper");
                    for (int j = 0; j < studentPaperNodeList.getLength(); j++) {
                        Element paperNodeElement = (Element)studentPaperNodeList.item(j);
                        System.out.println("\nCurrent paper :" + paperNodeElement.getTextContent());
                    }
                }

            }
            System.out.println("Number of students : "+nodeList.getLength());


        } catch (FactoryConfigurationError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```